# Working with C# and Excel Interop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xla.Visible = false;
Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;
ws.Name = "Serial";
int i = 1;
foreach (DataRow comp in dsView.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ws.Cells[i, 1] = "'" + comp[0].ToString();
    ws.Cells[i, 2] = "'" + comp[1].ToString();
    ws.Cells[i, 3] = "'" + comp[2].ToString();
    i++;
}
if (File.Exists(@"d:\DDD.xlsx"))
    File.Delete(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");
xla.Save(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");    ---->>>>  on this line i get the error
```

The error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I am working on C# [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) with Office 2012

Comment: Provide full stack trace, please. Maybe the file name or path does not exist or the file is being used by another program. Try use SaveAs instead Save.

Comment: do you/does your app have all the rights to write to this folder?

Comment: first step run the code until this point and try to save manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the variable xla is your excel application and not a workbook.  You want to save the workbook.

so

```
xla.Save(@"d:\DDD.xlsx");    ---->>>>  on this line i get the error
```

should be

```
wb.SaveAs(@"d:\DDD.xlsx", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Comment: In all the excel interop code I have, I'm using the save method on the workbook

Answer (score 0):

When I run `Excel.Application.Save()` with Visual Studio 2010 and Excel 2010 interop (Office 14) targeting .NET 4, it displays a dialog to select a location to save the file. Clicking Cancel on that dialog results in a COM exception. But clicking Save has odd results: When I supply a valid file path and name as a parameter like `Excel.Application.Save(@"C:\blah.xlsx")`, I end up with two files saved. The first is named Sheet1.xlsx and contains what I'd expect, even though I didn't choose that name in the dialog. The other is named blah.xlsx (as per my file name parameter) and won't open correctly in Excel. If I call `Excel.Application.Save()` without a file name as a parameter, a valid file is saved with the name and path I selected in the dialog, but I also get a "RESUME.XLW" file as well. So it seems that the `Application.Save` method may not be a good choice to use. Instead, you can do something like this, which works as you'd expect:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook book = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.ActiveSheet;
            sheet.Name = "Booya";
            Excel.Range range = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
            range.Value = "This is some text";
            book.SaveAs(@"C:\blah.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```